# MFC CFTPConnection : How to reset the directory

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ftp

I am facing issues with FTP folder resetting using the class CFTPConnection.
My development environment is VC++6.0 and MFC.
I am able to create subfolders in the FTP using the function "CreateDirectory" of CFTPConnection  class (FTP Server is in RHEL using vsftpd package).
But not able to find the function to go back to the root folder or parent folder.

Kindly anyone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks and Regards,
Alvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you want is [CFtpConnection::SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650hk7z2.aspx) which simply uses [FtpSetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to change the directory.

Since [FtpSetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) accepts:

> Pointer to a null-terminated string that contains the name of the
>   directory to become the current working directory. This can be either
>   a fully qualified path or a name relative to the current directory.

You should be able to navigate using relative paths like ".." to go back a folder or to reset to parent folder something like "/".